# Why do my dimmer switches keep burning out?

Tags: electrical, lighting, recessed-lighting

I have a Lutron Maestro MACL-153MH (600W incandescent/halogen) controlling 5 x H1499ICAT (low-voltage, MR-16, 50W each) in my vacation house. So, that's a total of 250W. It burned out one day, so I replaced it. After I replaced it, I noticed that 2 of the light were out and replacing the bulbs didn't help, so I figured that the housing burned out. The remaining 3 were working though. Next time I got to the house (and I actually had some time to order and replace the housings) the dimmer was burned out again, so I replaced it to see how many lights were still working, but as soon as I reset the breaker after the new dimmer was installed I heard a click coming from the dimmer and a burning smell... So, the another dimmer is gone...

Any ideas what might be wrong and what to check? Is it possible that those 2 burned out housings cause that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is 'low voltage' lights on an incandescent/halogen dimmer.

Here is information on dimmer types, and will help you find the right one

http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Education-Training/Pages/LCE/DimmingBasics.aspx

Comment: A summary of the information on the linked page would be a good addition to the answer, just in case Lutron, say, redoes their site and breaks the link.

Answer (score 0):

If replacing the bulbs did not help you might have a short in the fixture.  By pass switch and turn on the breaker will confirm. But likely either a bad socket or transformer because the wrong dimmer was used.

It is possible with today's modern low volt lights for the lights to have a electronic transformer instead of the traditional magnetic type.

Electronic puck light transformers will work fine with incandescent halogen dimmers.  To find out which one you have you will have to test the frequency as electronic puck light transformers step up the frequency to 20k Hertz whereas magnetic transformers are the normal 50/60 Hertz.